# Which of the following matrices cannot be obtained by elementary row operations on the matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, symmetric-matrices

Which of the following matrices cannot be obtained by elementary row operations on the matrix

$$A = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 \end{matrix}\right]$$

1. $ \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$
2. $ \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{matrix}\right]$
3. $ \left[\begin{matrix} 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$
4. $ \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 \end{matrix}\right]$

My Thinking :-

$A$ is invertible.

Every matrix in the options is invertible and so there's  no way of discarding the options by rank.

But I run into trouble with the following arguments:-

Sincs $A$ is invertible , the identity matrix $I_3$ can be obtained by elementary row operations on the matrix $A$ .

Let us say, $I_3=PA \quad (1)$

where $P$ is an invertible matrix.

Again if $B$ be any other invertible matrix , there exist invertible matrix $Q$ such that

$B=QI_3 \quad (2)$

So from $(1)$ and $(2)$ , we have

$B=(QP)A$, where $QP$ is invertible.

Thus every invertible matrix is obtainaible from every other invertible matrix  by elementary row operations !!

Thus none of the given options should be an answer !

Am I overlooking something or is the question wrong ? Need your help.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I haven't checked if all the matrices are invertible. However, it is true that two matrices $A$ and $B$ are equivalent by row operations if and only if $\ker A=\ker B$. Therefore, your point stands.

Comment: You're right. It is indeed true that all of the matrices in question are invertible, from which it follows that all matrices are row-equivalent. In particular, they all have the identity matrix as their reduced row echelon form. So, unless the asker is using a non-standard definition of an "elementary row operation," there is a mistake in the question and none of the answers is correct.

Comment: @BenGrossmann  No sir , I am using  the standard definitions of elementary row operations . Thanks for your comment. Just for the sake of my curiousity, can you please point out what are the indicators that a matrix is obtained by elementary row operations from another given matrix other than the rank ?

Comment: @user710290 It is exactly as the first comment says; note that "ker" in this context is synonymous with "nullspace". Equivalently, two matrices are row equivalent if and only if they have the same reduced row echelon form, and from there we can use the fact that there is exactly one invertible matrix in reduced row echelon form.